# How do I force Firebase Cloud Functions to use ESLint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What is the command to enable ESLint for my cloud functions?

For a bit of background info, I ran `firebase init` and did the set up, but for some reason it was using ESLint instead of TSLint. I redid the `firebase init` and this time I answered "No" when it asked if I wanted to use ESLint. However, as the comments pointed out, ESLint is now favored and TSLint is deprecated. So now I need to re-enable ESLint for this project.

Comment: TSLint was deprecated some years ago and wasn't updated for a long time. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: ESLint supercedes TSLint.

Comment: @jabaa Ahh ok. Well I guess I still have the same question, just for ESLint. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

This Video below is a great starter on how to set up your cloud functions including your mentioned eslint, typescript, very informative
[Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0)

Comment: Yea I was hoping there was a simple command to enable it. But yea I'll just re-run the `firebase init` I guess.

Comment: this video helped my a lot setting my cloud functions environment.

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at the repository for the [`firebase-tools`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) utility, you can find the templates used in the `firebase init` command.

For linting with `eslint`, you will need the following files:

- [`.eslintrc.js`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/_eslintrc),
- [`package.json`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/package.lint.json), and
- [`tsconfig.dev.json`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/tsconfig.dev.json)

Once you have updated those files appropriately, run `npm install` in your `functions` directory so that the required libraries are downloaded.

You will also need to add these lines to your `firebase.json` file in your project directory so that your functions are linted and transpiled before deployment.

```js
// PROJECT_DIR/firebase.json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    /* ... */
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

[`.eslintrc.js`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/_eslintrc), [`package.json`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/package.lint.json), and [`tsconfig.dev.json`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/templates/init/functions/typescript/tsconfig.dev.json), as they were at the time of writing, have been included below for convienience. Please consult their respective links if obtaining them in the future as they may have changed.

```js
// PROJECT_DIR/functions/.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
  },
};
```

```js
// PROJECT_DIR/functions/package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
// PROJECT_DIR/functions/tsconfig.dev.json
{
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.js"
  ]
}
```